# how to change the contents in the file in perl?

Tags: perl, file

I am trying to open one file read oneline in it at a time then open the another file and try to search for some part of the line read from the first file in the second file and try to replace all instances with the other part of the line read from the first file.When i am executing it its getting executed and i am able to see the result on the console but the files are not getting modified. What could be the mistake. Can some one please suggest this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # die if problem reading or writing a file

my $filename = 'compare.txt';
open(my $fh, '+<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";



while(<$fh>){
    my $readline= "$_";

    print("\n");

    my @arr=split(',',$readline);
    print($arr[0]."\n".$arr[1]);
    replace($arr[0],$arr[1]);

}
close $fh;

sub replace
{
    my $search=shift(@_);
    my $replace=shift(@_);

    my $filename2 = 'replace.txt';
    open(my $fh1, '+<', $filename2) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    while(<$fh1>)
    {
        my $readline2= "$_";
        $readline2=~s/$search/$replace/g;
        print($readline2);
        print("\n");

   }
   close $fh1;

}
```

Comment: You never write your replacements to files, but just print to the console.  Need to write a new file (with changes) and then move it over the file which needs to be changed.

Comment: Don't need (and don't use) `+<` mode; just `open my $fh, '<', $file ...` for reading.

Comment: Can do `while (my $readline = <$fh>) { .. }` and `$readline` is assigned the line (what would've been in `$_`) and exists (is seen) in the loop.

Comment: Put `use feature 'say';` at the top and you can print as `say "hi";` where newline gets appended. Then you can use `print` specifically when you don't want a newline, `say` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As a huge fan of the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module, I would do the above as:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my %rep = map { split /,/ } path('compare.txt')->lines({chomp => 1});
path("replace.txt")->edit_lines( sub {
    while(my($key,$val) = each(%rep)) {
        s/$key/$val/g;
    }
});
```

Comment: _Hey, how cool is this?_ And it avoids the complete rewrite of the target file for every single replacement.

Comment: Awesome. +1 for succinctness

Answer (score 1):

In your sub, when you are iterating the lines in your file, you should write it back to a file. The regex substitute doesn't automatically write it back to file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # die if problem reading or writing a file
use File::Copy;
my $filename = 'compare.txt';
open(my $fh, '+<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";



while(<$fh>){
        my $readline= "$_";

        print("\n");

        my @arr=split(',',$readline);
        print($arr[0]."\n".$arr[1]);
        replace($arr[0],$arr[1]);

}
close $fh;

sub replace
{
        my $search=shift(@_);
        my $replace=shift(@_);

        my $filename2 = 'replace.txt';
        open(my $fh1, '+<', $filename2) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
#open file to write to
        open $newfile, '>', 'replace_tmp.txt';
        while(<$fh1>)
        {
                chomp;
                my $readline2= "$_";
                $readline2=~s/$search/$replace/g;
                print( $newfile, $readline2);
                print($newfile, "\n");
        }
        close($fh1);
        close($newfile);
        move ('replaced.txt', 'replace.txt');
}
```

This is simple way of doing it. You can use [File::Tie](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-1.00/lib/Tie/File.pm) to write back to the same file and avoid renaming it, or refer to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?)